# Cakephp admin url routing not working

Tags: cakephp, routes, admin

I have developed a large website in CakePHP. On development time my admin URL was `SITE_URL/admin`. Now my client wants it with lc_admin. So I change prefixes in `core.php` file but when I tried to access any page it shows me error that `lc_admin_index()` action is not defined. Because my actions are with admin_index and so on.

To solve this issue I tried code below

```
Router::connect('/lc_admin/:controller', array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/lc_admin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));`
```

But with this my old URL called `SITE_URL/admin` also working. And I want new URL accessible.

Comment: Mponos, Please did you know solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want direct route path by keyword then use simple.
Route path

```
Router::connect('/lc_admin',array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: but i want to disable /admin url also.

Comment: In this it will only shows SITE_URL/lc_admin it will not display controller and action

Answer (score 0):

you should give the prefix the same value, as you have in your url, please try this:

```
Router::connect('/lc_admin/:controller', array('prefix' => 'lc_admin', 'admin' => true));   
Router::connect('/lc_admin/:controller/:action', array('prefix' => 'lc_admin', 'admin' => true));   
Router::connect('/lc_admin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'lc_admin', 'admin' => true));
```

also, please note, that all your actions (that are called with this url pattern) should have prefix `admin_` or you should change it accordingly.

Comment: Is there any solutions so that I did not need to change my all actions and .ctp files prefixes..??
Because there are too many controller and too many functions so i cant change admin_index() to lc_admin_index() and so on...
When i used above  code its show me 
`The action lc_admin_index is not defined in controller...`

Comment: issue is that when i open `admin/controller_name` then its working..but its should not work...it should work only if there is `/lc_admin/controller_name`